# Content Query WebPart not showing hyperlink

Tags: content-query-web-part, hyperlink, item-styles

I am quite new to Content Query WebPart.
I have a list which as a 'Hyperklink or Picture' column.
I have added below markup in itemstyle.xsl  to show hyperlink

```
<xsl:template name="CQWPStyle" match="Row[@Style='CQWPStyle']" mode="itemstyle">
 <html>
<table width="100%">
<xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::*)=0">
    <tr>
    <td width="10%" valign="top"><div class="item"><b>Title</b></div></td>
    <td width="10%" valign="top"><div class="item"><b>Address</b></div></td>
    <td width="10%" valign="top"><div class="item"><b>Area</b></div></td>   
    <td width="10%" valign="top"><div class="item"><b>ChoiceCol</b></div></td>  
    <td width="10%" valign="top"><div class="item"><b>DateTimeCol</b></div></td>    
</tr>
</xsl:if>
<tr>       
    <td width="10%" valign="top">
        <div class="item">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Title" />
        </div>
    </td>
    <td width="10%" valign="top">
        <div class="item">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Address" disable-output-escaping="yes"  />
        </div>
    </td>
    <td width="10%" valign="top">
        <div class="item">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Area" />
        </div>
    </td>
    <td width="10%" valign="top">
        <div class="item">
            <xsl:value-of select="@ChoiceCol" />
        </div>
    </td>
        <td width="10%" valign="top">
        <div class="item">
            <xsl:value-of select="@DateTimeCol" />
        </div>
    </td>
    <td width="10%" valign="top">
        <div class="item">          
            <!--Variable declared to read the link from the column Link-->

            <xsl:variable name="ActualLink" select="substring-before(@HyperLinkCol,',')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="FriendlyName" select="substring-after(@HyperLinkCol,',')"/>

            <!-- Image to the hyperlink-->

<a href="{$ActualLink}"><xsl:value-of select="$FriendlyName"/></a>



        </div>
    </td>        
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

All other columns show as expected. However, the hyperlink column does not show.
Kindly let me know, what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

**[Updated]**

```
<xsl:variable name="BeforeLink">   
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@HyperLinkCol, ',')" />                        
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="AfterLink">   
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@HyperLinkCol, ',')" />                     
</xsl:variable>

//// Use those variables
<a href="{$BeforeLink}">
     <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$AfterLink"/>
 </a>
```

---

Instead of assigning values in variable and then using those variables, try to use the values directly.

If you want to display only link, use following code:

```
<a href="{substring-before(@HyperLinkCol,',')}"><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@HyperLinkCol,',')"/></a>
```

And if you want to display am image, use below code-snippet:

```
<img src="{substring-before(@HyperLinkCol,',')}" alt="{substring-after(@HyperLinkCol,',')}" />
```

Comment: Tried above markup. Still no luck. it renders output as '<a href=""></a>'

Comment: I have updated my code.

Comment: Thanks for the trails divya. However it is still not working. I used your updated markup

Comment: Any update please....

Comment: I believe this is a very basic question for Stack Exchange users. Till now 27 views but no working answer yet... Any pointer / link will also help me move forward. Thank you.

Comment: Please any body who can help...

Comment: Can any body share a working sample / link where i can get hyperlink column displayed...